# making unique records in MS access

Tags: ms-access

I have 1.7 million records in an access table sorted A to Z. the records are not unique and there are repeated records. I want to make them unique based on their frequency. if a record has been repeated 4 times I want the first one to get "-1" at the end of the record value, the second record get "-2" and so on. in this way similar records will become unique. all similar record are beside each other because of sorting. in excel I do this task by an If function (if this cell value<>the cell value above then "1" else above repeat number plus 1) but in access I don't know what to do (I'm a beginner).
finally I want to add a column to original table which is (original record value - repeat number).

I appreciate your help

Comment: There are better ways ofmakingrecords unique, like using a unique identifier with `AutoNumber`.  Is there a reason you require negative numbers?

Comment: It might be easier for you to move the data to Excel, make the change you desire and import data back into Access.

Comment: @zedfoxus, exporting 1.7 millin records to excel needs a macro to deal with row number limit in excel sheets and export the rest of the access table to a second sheet automatically

Comment: @ashleedawg, it's not negative sign it's dash for example 21346549743161-1 to separate repeat number from the original value. I cannot use autonumber because I have another table as large and in the end I want to compare records in the two tables and find unmatched records. so 21346549743161-1 must be the same in both tables

Comment: Please clarify, when you say "records are not unique", do you mean that literally that entire records (every field) contains exactly the same data, or do you mean only certain columns of the record (a.k.a. row) contain duplicate data, accompanied by other columns that have different data?  If the rows are literally exactly the same, then honestly it is pointless in a relational database to store the records more than once.  Instead, just create another field, e.g. Repeated, that contains how many repeats.  This still allows comparison between two tables, but is now normalized.

Comment: However, if it's critical to keep the duplicate rows, then I suggest adding another field rather than appending something to an existing field.  This is perfectly legitimate and common in relational databases, and a unique index can be defined on the two combined fields.

Comment: @Perkins, records are payment transactions data. definitely in whole data are unique for each record, but in a certain column, payment id, for some reasons they are not unique( seemingly errors in reports or something else). my data is from two sources, receiver and sender. I have to match the records, even seemingly repeated records to each other and rule them out (anyway sender has reported sending and receiver has confirmed). in the end records remain that have been reported on one side but not on the other (e.g. the fourth repeat of a payment-Id doesn't match, the other 3 match).

Comment: @Perkins, by the way, I cannot make a unique field by simply appending all columns data for a row to make a unique value. because there are omissions and alterations in those fields in the two sources, i.e. although they are unique in their own table but they do not match their counterpart in the other source. so for a given record only payment-Id has not changed and is reliable, the other fields do not match, (e.g. payment date is different on the side of sender and receiver)

Comment: If your data is from two sources, you should use two separate tables and compare the data using one or more queries and/or VBA.

Comment: @Rene, I already have two separate tables, each containing around 1.7 million records. I need a unique field to compare them and the best filed is payment-id, but because there are repeated payment-ids in this field, I need to distinguish them by a repeat identifier so that while comparing tables, the first payment-id goes for the first one in the opposite table and the 2nd and 3rd and ... in the end for each payment-id, either all records match or some remain unmatched in one table, e.g. payment-id-4

Comment: Then you should adjust your question as it states "I have 1.7 million records in an access table sorted A to Z".

Comment: @Rene, yes but comparing two tables was the next step. here I just needed a way to give repeat identifiers to a field in one table and the solution would be the same for both tables

Comment: SELECT Data.RefNo, Count(Data.ID) AS Dupes, Max(Data.DupeIndex) AS IndexMax
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.RefNo
HAVING Count(Data.ID) > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Note about sort order:

Sort order in a relational database is not concrete like in a spreadsheet.  There is no concept of rows being "next to each other", unless in context of an index.  An index is largely a tool for the database to handle the data more efficiently (and to aid in defining uniqueness).  The order itself is still largely dynamic because the order of a particular query can be specified differently from the index (or from storage order) and this does *not* change how the data is actually stored.  Being "next to each other" is essentially a useless concept in SQL queries, unless you mean "next to each other **numerically**", for instance with an AutoNumber field or with the "repeat numbers" you want to add.  Unlike in a spreadsheet, you cannot refer to the row "just above this row" or the "row offset by 2 from the 'current' row".

## Solution

1. Regardless of whether or not you will use the AutoNumber column later, **add a Long Integer AutoNumber column** anyway.  This column is named `[ID]` in the example code.  Why?  Because until you add something to allow the database to differentiate between the rows, there is technically no way using standard SQL to reliably reference individual duplicates since there is no way to distinguish individual rows.  Even though you say that there are other differentiating columns, your own description rules out using them as a reliable key in referring to specific rows.  (Even without such a differentiating column, Access can technically distinguish between rows. Iterating through a DAO.Recordset object in VBA would work, but perhaps not very elegant / efficient.)
2. Also **add a new integer column for counting repeats**, which below is named `[DupeIndex]`.  A separate field is preferred (necessary?) because it allows continued reference to the original, unaltered duplicate values.  If the reference number were directly updated, it would no longer match other fields and so would not be easily detected as a duplicate anymore.  The following solution relies on grouping of ALL duplicate values, even those already "marked" with a `[DupeIndex]` number.

   - You should also realize that in comparing different data sets, that having separate fields allows more flexibility in matching the data.  Having the values appended to the reference number complicates comparison, since you likely not only want to compare rows with the same duplication index, rather you will want to compare all possible combinations.  For example, comparing records `123-1` in one set to `123-4` in another... how do you select such rows in an automated fashion?  You don't want to have to manually code all combinations, but that's what you'll end up doing if you don't keep them separate like {`123`,`1`} and {`123`,`4`}.
3. Create and save this as a named query `[Duplicates]`.  This query is referenced by later queries.  It could instead be embedded as a sub query, but my preferences is to use saved queries for easier visualization and debugging in Access:

---

```
SELECT Data.RefNo, Count(Data.ID) AS Dupes, Max(Data.DupeIndex) AS IndexMax
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.RefNo
HAVING Count(Data.ID) > 1
```

4. Execute the following to create a temporary table with new duplicate index values:

---

```
SELECT D1.ID, D1.RefNo,
    IIf([Duplicates].[IndexMax] Is Null,0,[Duplicates].[IndexMax])
    + 1 
    + (SELECT Count(D2.ID) FROM Data As D2
       WHERE D2.[RefNo]=[D1].[RefNo] 
         And [D2].[DupeIndex] Is Null 
         And [D2].[ID]<[D1].[ID]) AS NewIndex
INTO TempIndices
FROM Data AS D1 INNER JOIN Duplicates ON D1.RefNo = Duplicates.RefNo
WHERE (D1.DupeIndex Is Null);
```

5. Execute the update query to set the new duplicate index values:

---

```
UPDATE Data 
INNER JOIN TempIndices ON Data.ID = TempIndices.ID
SET Data.DupeIndex = [NewIndex]
```

6. Optionally remove the AutoNumber field and now assign the combined [RefNo] and new [DupeIndex] as primary key.  The temporary table can also be deleted.

### Comments about the queries:

- Solution assume that `[DupeIndex]` is Null for unprocessed duplicates.
- Solution correctly handles existing duplicate index numbers, only updating duplicate rows without an unique index.
- Access has rather strict conditions for UPDATE queries, namely that updates are not based on circular references and/or that that joins will not produce multiple updates for the same row, etc.  The temporary table is necessary in this case, since the query determining new index values refers multiple times in sub queries to the very column that is being updated.  (If the update is attempted using joins on the subqueries, for example, Access complains that `Operation must use an updatable query`.)

Comment: @perkins,  thanks a lot for help. complete and perfect solution